# How to disable popups about IDE interactions in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

How do I disable these popups in IntelliJ that show up after almost each interaction with IDE?

These popups appear if I minimize a tab or start tomcat or execute any code or start debugger, etc.
I tried unchecking all options in **Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > Notifications** but they still appear.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build: 182.3911.36

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have the [Key Promoter Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1003-key-promoter) (or, less likely, the [Key Promoter X Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9792-key-promoter-x)) installed.

You can disable/uninstall this plugin from `Preferences > Plugins`.

Here's a screenshot (note the `Uninstall` button on the right hand side):

[image]